# GULP Error internal/child_process.js:298 throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

until yesterday I was using Gulp and it jsut worked.

Today I get this errormsg:

```
   internal/child_process.js:298
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:339:9)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/htdocs/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/opn/index.js:76:24)
    at Object.utils.open (/var/www/html/htdocs/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/../node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:173:23)
    at Object.utils.openBrowser (/var/www/html/../htdocs/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/../node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:163:23)
    at EventEmitter.events.service:running (/var/www/html/../htdocs/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/../node_modules/browser-sync/lib/internal-events.js:45:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at /var/www/html/.../htdocs/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/../node_modules/browser-sync/lib/browser-sync.js:260:19
```

Since I am just using gulp I have no idea what could cause this error. Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you as a user don't have permission to access what gulp is trying to access. Try running the same as `sudo` user.

EDIT by Bernhard Prange:
I gave the files now execution rights too. That solved it.

Comment: That's possible... I ran userrights new for this installation. What files are the problem?

Comment: I ran it now as root, but it doesn't help matters.

Comment: @BernhardPrange You can answer your own question, you don't need to edit another answer. It sounds like you found the answer but it wasn't related to this answer.

Comment: Yes Jon, I know. And No Jon, I was editing on purpose, since Kunal brought me to that anwer. Anyway - if you know better, I leave this partial answer here.

Comment: @BernhardPrange I am having this same issue. Can you please tell me to which files did you give the execution rights? Because, I tried running the gulp task after giving execution rights to the files inside my `/usr/lib/nodejs/internal` directory, but got the same error.

Comment: running with sudo didn't help, but giving execute permission (+x) worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Oh great, I solved this issue with a "chmod 777 -R *" for the whole project-path. Not the best way... But maybe its help someone...